# How do I get an unique ID per transaction which has multiple insertions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I had two text boxes in frond end which is productname and No.of.batches...For example I selected a product 'X' and No.of batches as 10..It will get 10 rows and user will insert the data when user clicks submit it will reflect in database too...My requirement is generate an ID automatically PER transaction...I had to get an unique ID for the whole operation...what should i do to get that?

Comment: Make identity column ..

Comment: I used identity but it is getting new transaction id for every insertion but i want ir for single transaction which has multiple insertions

Comment: I think then your question should how have one transaction id for bach. In  that case create a bumy batch table generate identity there and use for a batch or you can use squence ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about financial as opposed to database transactions but the same applies to both.

1. Per prdb's ansswer above, create a table for storing the transaction header information (don't call it transaction since that is a reserved word).  Call it something else.
2. Add appropriate foreign keys referencin that table.

Then your insert looks like this:

1. insert into the transaction header table and use OUTPUT or another select to get the id out
2. Insert into the other tables adding the transaction header id as a foreign key as needed.

Again, that's pretty standard with financial transactions.  For db transactions, the same approach could be used.

Comment: Am sure `transactions` is not a keyword check closely there is a `s`  at the end ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new table called transactions with auto generated column.

```
Create table transactions 
(
transaction_id int identity(1,1) Primary key,
product_name varchar(50),
No_of_batches int
)
```

Whenever there is a new transaction then first add a entry in transaction table and refer the auto generated value(`transaction_id`) in your target table for all the `X` records

Comment: Check This Once @Prdp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287691/replace-a-computed-column-with-a-logic-that-works-with-insert