# replace a computed column with a logic that works with INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `tblPacks`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPacks]
    (
        [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [BatchNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
        [PackID] VARCHAR(50),
        [Status] [int] NULL
    )
```

And a stored procedure `spInsertPacks`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertPacks
@ID INT,
@BatchNumber VARCHAR(30),
@Count INT
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblPacks 
Values
    (
        @ID,
        @BatchNumber, 
        CONVERT([varchar](50),
        'PK'+
            case 
                when len(@ID)<=(3) then CONVERT([varchar](20),right((0.001)*@ID,(3)),0) 
                else CONVERT([varchar](20),@ID,0) 
            end,0),0)
END
```

If ID of data type INT inserted in an order like 1,2,3,4,5... the above logic works fine.  But there is no restriction for a user to enter random numbers.  I want a stored procedure to generate `PackID(PK001,PK002..)` sequence in order, irrespective of `@ID` and `ID`.  Cannot be an identity Column.  How can I do that?
Actually This PackID is a barcode If barcode already existed for Pack then that sequence may not be same with the sequence we used and Newly generated barcodes which we are generating will be in seuquence PK001
Sample Output:-

```
ID BatchNumber PackID     Status
 1    b1           PK001    0
 1    b2           Pk002    0
 5    b7           ABC768   0
 3    b2           PK003    0
```

Comment: Ever use a sequence? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: Iam Using SQL SERVER 2008 version It Doesn't Support Sequence

Comment: Simulated easily enough but it has to use identity in a separate table. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askjay/2012/10/08/sequence-objects-in-sql-2012-and-sql-2008/

Comment: How about an insert trigger, get the `Max(PackID)` and increment by 1?

Comment: Can You Please Write some sample code I didnlt get You @WEI_DBA

Comment: max(packID) may run into race conditions.

Comment: @xQbert. I thought of that too after I posted comment...

Comment: What about changing the flow - change ID to an identity column, packID to a computed column based on ID and have the procedure instead return the inserted ID to the application for its own tracking purposes?

Comment: No ID cannot be Identity and Unique @JaazCole

Comment: Can you explain why identity is not an option?  If we understand the limitations you have to work with, it should improve the answers you receive.

Comment: Actually It is a foreign Key It references a column in another table...But I didn't wrote that in my question to make it simple.. @destination-data

Comment: Of course, identity doesn't have to be the primary key.  It could be a field, used only for seeding your PackId field.

Comment: Edited now check once You may get some idea @destination-data

Comment: Unless you can provide the business logic for generating a barcode, I don't see how this question can be answered.

Comment: Actually there will be Registration table with columns Quantity and Batch Number etc Based on Quantity PackID will be generate If Quantity is 3 then 3 ID's will be generated in table Packs With respect to Batch number that's the most summed explanation I can give @destination-data

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the logic a bit for generating `PackID`

Add a new column(`identifier`) for identifying the code and use it for `PackID` generation and for sequence use `Identity` column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPacks]
  (
     Iden_ID       INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     [ID]          [INT] NOT NULL,
     [BatchNumber] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
     [Identifier]  [VARCHAR](50),
     [PackID] AS [Identifier]
        + CASE
            WHEN Iden_ID <= 999 THEN RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), ID), 3)
            ELSE CONVERT([VARCHAR](20), ID, 0)
          END,
     [Status]      [INT] NULL
  )
```

To check the working

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblPacks]
            ([ID],identifier,[BatchNumber],[Status])
VALUES      (1,'pk','bat',1)

SELECT *
FROM   [tblPacks]
```

Comment: I cannot Write computed logic during Creation Because PackID can be Anything There is no restriction that should be in PK0001 Some times other values may also insert So I used that logic in Insert statement

Comment: @saibharath - check now

Comment: Sorry If Iam Annoying I Have been trying this from today Morning Ending up Some where Couldn't FInd solution Here Now I had first two rows as Pk001,Pk002 And Can I Insert BC571 as third Row?

Comment: @saibharath - You can insert `BC571` as third row. Make sure the Insert statement looks like this `INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblPacks]
            ([ID],identifier,[BatchNumber],[Status])
VALUES      (571,'BC','bat',1)`

Comment: Will Try and Update you Thank You So Much

Comment: No It's Not Working...I Think you didn't get the question...Assume I gave first record ID value as 1 and then Pack ID Pk001 But when I give ID as 5 It is  PK005..That's the problem It shouldn't be dependent on ID Value Even though ID value is 5 for second record Pack ID Should be PK003 @Prdp

Comment: Then you need a Identity column for sequence. Check now updated. If no then add list input and its respective result your question is not clear at all

Comment: My bad ID cannot be Identity and Unique Can't create a stored procedure and declare ID variable and Use some loops Is this Work @Prdp?

Comment: @saibharath - Add list of inputs atleast 5 different inserts and its respective result

Comment: got any Idea?,,,,